# Ingresar fecha de un datetimepicker vacio [delphi ]

Tags: delphi, datetimepicker

Como puedo Ingresar una fecha de un datetimepicker vacio desde el teclado como si fuera un TEdit1. Como aparece en esta imagen 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Personalmente no acabo de entender muy bien lo que necesitas. Seguramente tú lo tienes claro, pero no está de más dedicarle un poco de tiempo a explicar los problemas y las necesidades. Normalmente "mejores preguntas" redundan en "mejores respuestas".

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo que a @Germán.

Comment: Edite la imagen lo que busco hacer es lo que mencione anteriormente ingresar una fecha a un datetimepicker vacio como si fuera un tedit(los tedit estan como referencia) pero desde el teclado y no dando click al datetime y buscar una fecha que desee

Comment: Navega con tabulador hasta el control y puedes ingresar la fecha. ¿no?

Comment: @jachguate No lo puedo hacer, cuando llego al control intento ingresar una fecha no queda grabada

Comment: Justo acabo de probarlo en una aplicación VCL con Delphi Tokio, y no tengo problemas para poner la fecha. ¿Qué versión de Delphi estás utilizando?

Comment: Me pasa igual que a @jachguate. Tal como lo explicas no tiene sentido pues no es el comportamiento normal de un TDateTimePicker. Es más, es que en el componente normal no es posible dejar la fecha en blanco. Haz un CTRL+C sobre el componente y un CTRL+V aquí (o en tu pregunta inicial), para ver las propiedades del componente (en el DFM).

Comment: Los MaskEdit me soluciono el problema